# ElasticSearch: is bool-must-term(3) equivalent to old terms with minimum_should_match 3

Tags: elasticsearch

This is no longer valid in ES:

```
"terms" : {
  "field": ["1", "2", "3"],
  "minimum_should_match": 3
}
```

What will be the difference if I write a `bool` with 3 `must-term` or 3 `should` with `"minimum_should_match": 3`

```
"bool" : {
    "must" : [
    {"term" : {"field" : "1"}},
    {"term" : {"field" : "2"}},
    {"term" : {"field" : "3"}}
    ]
  }
```

vs

```
"bool" : {
    "should" : [
    {"term" : {"field" : "1"}},
    {"term" : {"field" : "2"}},
    {"term" : {"field" : "3"}}
    ],
    "minimum_should_match": 3
  }
```

Is it all the same?

Comment: Both queries will yield exactly the same score and the same documents.

Comment: Thanks, I may delete it or if you answer I'll accept. There are actually 3 queries (I mean the old one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both (new) queries will yield exactly the same score and the same documents.

The old `terms` query with `minimum_should_match` would generate a `bool/should` query underneath, so it's pretty much equivalent to the third one.